# Why is Set.keys() not strictly equal to Set.values(), but set.keys is strictly equal to set.values?

Tags: javascript, set

Given this set, the iterator functions are strictly equal, but not when called:

```js
let set = new Set([1,2,'3']);

console.log(set.keys === set.values);              // true
console.log(set.keys === set[Symbol.iterator]);    // true
console.log(set.values === set[Symbol.iterator]);  // true
console.log(set.keys() === set.values());          // false

// console.log prints them the same way
console.log(set.keys());                           // [Set Iterator] { 1, 2, '3' }
console.log(set.values());                         // [Set Iterator] { 1, 2, '3' }

// Set iterator does not equal itself
let keys1 = set[Symbol.iterator]();
let keys2 = set[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(keys1 === keys2);                      // false
```

Per latest ECMAScript 2021 on [Set.prototype.keys](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-set.prototype.keys),

> The initial value of the "keys" property is the same function object as the initial value of the "values" property.

This is the definition of Set.prototype.values() for point of comparison:

> 24.2.3.10 Set.prototype.values ( )
> The following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let S be the this value.
> 2. Return ? CreateSetIterator(S, value).

### Question

Why is a set iterator not strictly equal to another set iterator generated in the same way from the same set object?

Comment: `set.keys() === set.values()` will compare two different iterator **objects**. Two different **objects** are always different to each other. [A simplified example](https://jsbin.com/toqoqep/1/edit?js,console) which doesn't throw in sets as a red herring in all of this.

Comment: It wouldn't be logical if the returned iterator objects were the same. What if you already iterated over one entry in `.keys()` and then iterated over one entry in what you got from `.values()` - you wouldn't expect `.values()` to now return the second entry as first result, would you? So it doesn't make sense for them to share their state.

Comment: The link to the duplicate and VLAZ's comment are great resources, and thanks to all involved. I consider this question to be answered.